# Why is there a difference on 'ini_get_all()' versus 'php -i' and the 'php.ini'

Tags: php, configuration, config, ini

I have to increase the configuration parameter 'upload_max_filesize' within my application from **2MB to 8MB**.

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
```

When accessing the file (within a docker container btw) or typing

```
php -i
```

I get **8MB**.

However, when dumping the value via

```
dump(ini_get_all());
```

or

```
dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
```

in my application, I still get **2MB** as maximal filesize for uploads.

Is there some sort of cache or local/global conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's using different config files. `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` is, as the path says, for *CLI*. So it affects only command line usage.

Check your `phpinfo()` to see which config file is used in your web server environment instead! Search for "Loaded configuration file".

The exact path depends on the web server setup. For Apache it could be `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` for example.

Comment: It was /apache2/php.ini indeed. A colleague helped me out and I just wanted to answer it myself right now :) Thanks for your fast answer.